# registerNib forCellReuseIdentifier not reusing cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Profiling my application and I see 25 instances of my cell (PZCell) in "Living" there should be around 7 if the tableview is dequeuing correctly. My code is below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PZCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] 
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PZCell"];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PZCell *aCell = (PZCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PZCell"];
    [aCell setResult:[self.result.results objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return aCell;
}
```

Setting the reuse identifier in the nib makes no difference. any help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Hi . Did you why this is happening ?

Comment: Will you please post the code for class PZCell.h and PZCell.m ? I think some thing is retaining the cell. Which is why it might be not getting deallocated.